# unique words dictionary remove special characters and numbers

Tags: python, import, python-re

I want to make a dictionary from a book, unfortunately I have a problem

```
import re

with open('vechny.txt', encoding='utf-8') as fname:
    text = fname.read()
    lst = list(set(text.split()))
    str1 = ' '.join(str(e) for e in lst)
    print(str1, file=open("1000.txt", "a", encoding='utf-8'))



in_file = open("1000.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8')
lines = in_file.read().split(' ')
in_file.close()

out_file = open("file.txt", "w", encoding='utf-8')
out_file.write("\n".join(lines))
out_file.close()
```

this script works well but need to remove special characters

, .-, ect ... from plain text

example have words Hay, split takes it as one word and therefore does not remove it

how to make text

```
input
Hay, hello,% lost. 15 čas řad
output im search is
hay hello lost cas rad
```

Comment: modified requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
import re
str1 = '#@-/abcüšščřžý'
r = re.findall(r'\b\d*[^\W\d_][^\W_]*\b', str1, re.UNICODE)
str2 = ''.join(r)
print(str2)
```

Comment: `from unidecode import unidecode
import re
str1 = 'Hay, hello,% lost. 15 čas řad'
uni=(unidecode(str1))
r = re.findall(r'\b\d*[^\W\d_][^\W_]*\b', uni, re.UNICODE)
str2 = ' '.join(r)
print(str2)`

Comment: Sorry I forgot that you also want to exclude numbers. But hope it was still helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re
re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', ' ', 'Hay, hello,% lost. 15')
```

Let me know if is ok!

Comment: my language is Czech
š ščřžý we have such letters: D all is delete  and numbers will also remove them all

Comment: and this script output` is hay hello lost 15` from english text

Comment: `input
Hay, hello,% lost. 15 čas řad
output im search is
hay hello lost cas rad` this im search now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
from unidecode import unidecode
import random
import re

random = (random.randint(1000, 2000))

n = (input("jmenosouboru:"))

with open(""+str(n)+".txt", encoding='utf-8') as fname:
    text = fname.read()
    r = re.findall(r'\b\d*[^\W\d_][^\W_]*\b', text, re.UNICODE)
    str2 = ' '.join(r)
    uni=(unidecode(str2))
    lst = list(set(uni.split()))
    str1 = ' '.join(str(e) for e in lst)
    lines = str1.split(' ')
    text1 = ("\n".join(lines))
    text2 = ''.join(filter(lambda x: not x.isdigit(), text1))
    print(text2, file=open(""+str(random)+"-.txt", "a", encoding='utf-8'))
    print("done")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).